# Access JVM options in Camel Context

Tags: java, apache-camel, jvm-arguments

I have JVM option to define each envrionment. It is something like -Denv="development".
How can I access this JVM option in camel context and decide my route based on the env value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [camel-properties](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html) component...

```
PropertiesComponent pc = context.getComponent("properties", PropertiesComponent.class);

from("direct:start").to("properties:{{cool.end}}");
```